# No such file or directory in saving a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

My code is here

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/test.png","wb") do |file|
      file.write(Base64.decode64(params[:image_data]))
    end
```

It gives us no such file or directory test.png i want to crate a file in images folder test.png and save data and my folder **permissions is write,read and access**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is , its looking for `test.png` in `#{Rails.root}/public/images/` folder, which is not there.

Try the same by putting a  dummy file with the name `test.png` in images folder then it will work.